# Controlling JVM size

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, tomcat7, virtual-memory

I have a java application that sometimes needs a lot of memory. Regularely it consumes 100-200 MB, but sometimes, for 1-2 minutes it consumes ~2 GB.

Because I have to support this scenario, I set the xmX to 2048.

The problem is that the GC will not release this memory unless the application needs more memory.
The server becomes slow and heavy, and I have no way to make this application to free the memory.

I tried to call System.gc() after that part without success.

Are there more VM parameters that can help here? Is there any way to force the GC to run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **some** does give back the memory to the operating system : The SerialGC and G1GC. If you use the throughput collector or the low-pause collector, the JVM won't release any memory to the OS.

You can have more details on this [article](http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=14).

Hope that helps !